# What is inverse Fourier transform of e^-|α|?

Tags: fourier-series, inverse, fourier-transform

I am using the mathematical convention but my answer in any case is not matching.

I have attached my approach below.[image]

Comment: This may be a difference between authors, but I have an extra $2\pi$ in the exponent in the IFT formula. Can you double-check that?

Comment: Yeah it's due to different conventions.